# QuerydslBinderCustomizer not working in Spring Data JPA 2.0.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to use the `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` to perform the usage of `@QuerydslPredicate` in my Rest controller.

I'm using a `@Repositoy` implementation to perform customized queries and joins with another tables representing the access level for the query.

Following the documentation

Current Spring JPA version that contains `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`: `spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar`

The problem:

I'm trying to apply a `like()` operation in the `serviceExecution.code` field, but I only receive the predicate based on `eq()` and the `customize` method is not called at all.

I also try to put the code inside a interface based `Repository`, without success.

The `Repository` implementation is this one:

```
@Repository 
public class ServiceExecutionQueryRepositoryImpl extends JpaQuerydslBaseRepository<Long, ServiceExecution> implements ServiceExecutionQueryRepository, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QServiceExecution>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ServiceExecution> {

    @Override
    public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QServiceExecution serviceExecution) {

        bindings.bind(serviceExecution.code).first((path, value) -> path.likeIgnoreCase(StringUtils.like(value)));
        // breakpoint never hit this method.
        // bindings is not applied to the query
        ... another bindings

    }
}
```

The Resource method call:

```
    @GetMapping("/service-executions")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<ServiceExecutionDTO>> getAllServiceExecutions(
        @RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters,
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = ServiceExecution.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<ServiceExecutionDTO> page = facade.findAll(parameters, predicate, pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The resulting query generated (seen in application logs) is always this one (including count query):

`select o from ... where code = ?`

Can anyone know what I'm possible missing? Is something related to the recent Spring Data JPA version?

Details:

It's a gradle using project for Spring Boot, apt is configured.
Except this issue, Querydsl is currently working as expected.

It's possible OK to check the `Predicates` on each method and transform to a like (I don't know if / know it's possible), but even being possible it doesn't sounds like a good workaround.

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.binding

One of tutorials that I have followed: https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling

Similar question: [Spring @QuerydslPredicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918824/spring-querydslpredicate-questions)

[QueryDsl web query on the key of a Map field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989336/querydsl-web-query-on-the-key-of-a-map-field) (Invalid because it uses a previous version of spring)
**EDIT**

It seems that `QuerydslBindingsFactory` is loading only interfaces for bindings.

I'm using a interface with `@NoRepositoryBean`, that is not listed in the map that search for custom bindings. Maybe this the cause for the  `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` not being called and added to the application bindings.

Anyway, I still don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just forgot to add your `ServiceExecutionQueryRepositoryImpl` as `bindings` parameter of `@QuerydslPredicate` annotation:

```
@GetMapping("/service-executions")
public ResponseEntity<Page<ServiceExecutionDTO>> getAllServiceExecutions(
    @RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters,
    @QuerydslPredicate(root = ServiceExecution.class, bindings = ServiceExecutionQueryRepositoryImpl.class) Predicate predicate, 
    Pageable pageable
) {
    Page<ServiceExecutionDTO> page = facade.findAll(parameters, predicate, pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

See may example: [sb-querydsl-sd-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-querydsl-sd-demo)